# asp.net gridview scrollintoview when gridview in user control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I had a gridview in a webform, with javascript for scrolling the selected item into view;  worked fine.

Then I moved the gridview to a user control, got it to work except for the scroll into view.

Here's how the scrollintoview works, or used to work.

> On gridview.itemselected, a unique value from the selected row is stored in a hidden field.
>   $(document).ready on the main page calls a javascript "scrollintoview" function.
>   The scrollintoview function gets the value from the hidden field, finds that value in the gridview, identifies the vertical location of that value, does a scroll to the appropriate vertical position, and sets the background-color of the gridview row to light yellow.

Again, that worked fine when the gridview was in the main form.

Now, with the gridview in the user control, the javascript executes correctly (I can watch it during debug), but when the gridview appears on the page, it has not scrolled.

So, maybe somewhere in the sequence of events, the gridview is being rendered after the scrollintoview has taken place?

Any suggestions on how to get this to work would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be tricky.  The way I've done it is to place the gridview in a div which looks like this:
               
Then in function setScrollValue the hiddenfield value is set to divGvMD.scrollTop.

When the page refreshes divGvMD.scrollTop is set to the hiddenfield value.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Yep, that's what I was doing...only, I did it badly.  When I rechecked my code, and lined up the variables properly, it worked fine.  FYI for anyone interested, the hidden fields are in the user control, and the JS is brought by external file into the user control, and the document.ready call is also in the user control, so it's all self-contained, and it all works fine.